# Patching a magic property on a class

Tags: python, mocking

I have a class like this:

```
class CrazyClass(object):
    ___self__ = random()
```

I need to work with this class in my unit tests and I need to set `__self__` to a predictable value like `None` or `0`. (Note that this is a contrived example, I'm not really generating a random number every time the class is initialized.)

How can I patch just this class property on `CrazyClass` for all of my test cases in my test class? I don't need any reference to a patched `CrazyClass`, I just need to set the value and have it be restored after the fact like so:

```
prev = CrazyClass.__self__
CrazyClass.__self__ = None
# do testing werk
CrazyClass.__self__ = prev
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What you showed in your "like so" is exactly the way you do it. (If you want to wrap that up in a context manager or something, you can, but that's a trivial addition.) So… what exactly are you asking?

Comment: setUp and tearDown methods?